# SP13 doesn't recognize list item changes when made by a workflow

Tags: designer-workflow, item

SP13 doesn't recognize any list item changes when they are made by a workflow. (2010 workflows did)
Therefore does not trigger any list workflows on "item change". Items need manual change to trigger workflows. not good...
Is there any easy way to bypass this?
(i ve found a complicated way by using call http & get dictionary, but that does not help in my case)
thanks

Comment: Can you provide details on the workflow and scenerio?  I assume you are using one workflow to update a secondary list.  If you use elevated permissions then this is expected (system account won't trigger workflow).

Comment: a list contains names, task descriptions and deadline. One workflow creates several tasks based on these fields. When the task is created I want to start a reminder workflow and a search for the supervisor of the person that the task was assigned to. All my workflows work perfectly on manual trigger. But the tasks created in the task list do NOT trigger workflow kick off "on item creation" or "item change".

Comment: what do you mean elevated permissions?

Comment: What is the "Created by" and "Modified by" columns show when that task is created from the first workflow?

Comment: Created by is my name. Not system account.

Comment: Do you know any way to solve this?

Comment: One more fact. These workflows are triggered automatically when designed as 2010 workflows.  But they not As 2013 ones.

Answer (score 1):

Workflows are not triggered by system accounts.  If your Task item is created under the System Account (or if the account used is flagged "to act as system") then workflow won't fire.

This can happen based on the account used to trigger the workflow directly or if your workflow uses elevated permissions.  I think in 2010 workflow this is called "Impersonation step" or similar.

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be to build the first workflow as a 2010 workflow, instead of a 2013 one.

Another might be to enable the Site Feature "Workflows can use app permissions", and if you are a Site Owner (have Full Control on the site), you should be able to use the "App Step" icon to create an Impersonation Step to do your update to the other list, to kick off its workflow.  We did not try this one because the first option was very easy and worked for us, since we did not have that many steps to re-create when we realized this.

Additional info:  msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj822159.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar problem today.  My SP13 WF was generating a task. I was using a SP10 WF to update it after a user Edit action on the task, but the SP13 WF wasn’t pickup the change made by the SP10 WF. Though manually updating the item always resulted in the SP13 WF catching that the item was updated. I tried  vapcguy approach of enabling the Site feature but that didn’t solve my problem.

Turns out there is a race condition that if the SP10 WF updates the task item too quickly the original WF wont pick up the change. The approach I used to bypass this race condition was to inject a wait state to the SP10 WF by using the Pause for a Duration action.